# how to get more decimal places in round function in R

Tags: r

i want more decimal places in round function.

if i give

```
data<-c(2.768687963684727856934786)

round(data,digits = 20)

2.76868796368473
```

in that result i got only 14 decimals only after decimal point, how can i get more decimals(means 20).
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try `options(digits = 20)`

Comment: actually you have all 20 decimals, but only 14 are displayed in the console because that's how the option `digits` is set in your session. You can try `sprintf("%.20f", round(data,digits = 20))` to display all 20 (though it will be converted into `character`)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as.numeric(sprintf("%.20f", round(data,digits = 20)))  is giving only 16 decimals only

Comment: Note that by default R uses [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers which are only accurate to about 16 digits.  If you need more then some arbritrary precision package like [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) is needed.